# Iterate through string in register

Tags: assembly

I have a string in the ebx register and I want to iterate through its bytes. I'm new to assembly and want to if this concept works.

```
#string is in ebx
movl (%ebx), %edi #put the adresse of the string to %edi
jmp looper

looper:

    cmpl $0, %edi             # check if byte at edi is 0 (it's a c conform string so 0 is the terminator)
    je exit 

    addl $8, %edi                # load next value, increment the edi by 8 to move it to the next byte of the string 
    jmp looper            # jump to loop beginning
```

Comment: By _"I have a string in the ebx register"_, do you mean that you the _address of_ the string in `ebx`? If so, this looks incorrect: `movl (%ebx), %edi #put the adresse of the string to %edi`.

Comment: I think it's the actual value. The string comes from the command line argument and is copied to %ebx with popl %ebx.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a particularly good idea. The `ebx` register can only hold 4 bytes, i.e. 4 ASCII characters (3 if you have a null terminator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string is physically contained in the EBX register then it is just impossible to calculate an address.

If the string is pointed to by the value in the EBX register then

```
movl (%ebx), %edi #put the adresse of the string to %edi
```

needs to be `movl %ebx,%edi`

The code `cmpl $0, %edi` will not check the byte at EDI but rather test if EDI itself is zero. Better use `cmpb $0,(%edi)`

Why would you add 8 to the EDI register when checking for bytes?